# I need to hash a PIN in Django that will always be the same

Tags: python, django, hash, passwords

I am making a Django project that will be hosted locally in different environments.

I want users to be able to login by just entering a six-digit PIN on a touch screen or keyboard instead of having to type out a lengthy username/password.

I need to store a PIN for users in the DB.  I want the PIN to be hashed or encrypted in some way so that it is not visible in the database.  The PIN (and therefore its hash) must be unique but it also must be converted to the same value each time.  For instance, every time 123456 is entered it needs to be converted to "jhs8d67RandomString34kds" so that no two users can save the same PIN as the DB column will be unique.

I need to know how to change a user-entered integer and hash it to save in the database.

Then I need to know how to compare it when a user enters the PIN.

I really need some examples on how to implement this and not a lesson in telling me why this is "insecure" or won't work.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need to hash it? Its already inherently insecure by only requiring a single random piece of information to access a random users account

Comment: You should always require another piece of information like a username, that way you can add a salt to the PIN hash and make it more secure. Without a salt you are vulnerable to rainbow table attacks

Comment: If an attacker somehow gets your database, they can simply brute force each PIN. Since your PIN is small, it would take only seconds. This is almost no effort at all. Your admins could do the same if they don't want to behave. Real security might be added if you could invalidate PINs after the first use or make them valid only for a limited amount of time, but only if your use case permits that. Also, online attacks on the PIN are also very feasible. This is similar to Zoom's issue with meeting IDs that were too short and everybody could enter other peoples random meetings.

Comment: Every comment did exactly what I asked you not to do.  This is in a controlled environment with controls in place to stop brute force attacks.  It can be locked after five failed login attempts.  Why can't you just help me with my question?

Comment: What about how often a user is allowed to change their pin? wouldn't take long for a user to get a list of all pins currently in use. its unclear what part of your question you're struggling with, how to hash a string or how to save a string in a database

Comment: to change a PIN the user has to know their old PIN... I need to know how to change this into a hash AND how to upload it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Hashing something doesn't make it secure
2. All hash function have clashes, the only difference is the probability
3. Integers have hash function [implemented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#hashing-of-numeric-types), just use that
4. Note that for security reasons hashing for strings in randomized in each python process. so those hashes cannot be used for persistent data

Comment: There are times when requiring a user to enter a lengthy username/email and a password are not optimal.  For instance, in a POS situation or even as an added layer like a signature PIN to apply a signature to a document.  I know how to do this in PHP but I don't know how to do it here.   When I do it with PHP, the value of a 4 digit PIN is stored like this "nfdYQbq3CaUR" and it is always sent to that string.  This way, no one can see the PIN in the DB.  Could you explain how to implement this?  I am confused by how hasihng a PIN to show that is not secure...

Comment: It is not secure if it is 1.Not salted 2.The only piece of information required for access.  As for the hasing itself, in python you use the `hash` function - if the number is stored in a var called `pin` you can do `hash(pin)`.  You can see examples here https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/hash

Comment: 1). It makes it so it can't be read, but can be guessed only if the pin is short and only numeric. That's nothing to do with the hash, it has more to do with the input. 2). The probability for SHA1 and similar is as if every known planet had the same computer power we did and used all of it to find a collision. It'd take until the heat death of the universe. We're not talking about MD5. 3). True, but don't use ints for pins, otherwise 1. 4). Hashing is persistent, where are you getting that information? Unless you mean the underlying hashmap used for dictionaries?

Comment: Since 3.3 python uses a random seed for hashing by default. You can read about it here https://docs.python.org/3.4/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONHASHSEED

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**module-hashlib**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#module-hashlib):

```
import hashlib

pincode = "123456"
hashlib.md5(pincode).hexdigest()
'e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e'
```

And the to compare you can do the same:

```
if hashlib.md5(pincode).hexdigest() == 'e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e':
    you code here
    ...
```

Or use **[hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac)** with salt:

> hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac(hash_name, password, salt, iterations, dklen=None)

```
import hashlib
dk = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha256', b'password', b'salt', 100000)
dk.hex()
'0394a2ede332c9a13eb82e9b24631604c31df978b4e2f0fbd2c549944f9d79a5'
```